# Maximum Likelihood Estimator of $\theta$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, parameter-estimation

I have the following question

> [image]

I tried to answer

I got answer that same like this answer

> [image]

Is this true answer? 
(Note that: in the question $0<p<\frac{1}{2}$, but in this answer $0<p<1$ )
Is this an effect observed in the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. You are maximizing the function on $[0,1]$, while you should maximize it on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$. From the definition of MLE $\hat{p}(x)=\arg\max \{L(x,p):p \in[0,\frac{1}{2}] \}$. 
The correct answer is $\bar{p}=\min\{\bar{x} ,\frac{1}{2} \}$.

 Also note that, if initially $p \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$, then maximum likehood estimator wouldn't exist.

Comment: Why it wouldn't exist. ?

Comment: Because $\bar{x}=0$ can happen with positive probability and you can't maximize likehood function for that $x$ on $(0,\frac{1}{2})$. Try to rewrite the attached proof with restriction to $p\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and then for $p\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: you mean open interval deference from closed interval in the question ??

Comment: Yes, I noted it because people often don't realize that MLE do not always exist even in relatively regular experiments.